# QTcpSocket will cause handles increase in windows

Tags: qt, qtcpsocket

I use qt4.8.5 and windows.
I use QTcpSocket to connect a server.
If the server doesn't open, then I will try to connect it.
My way is:

```
sock = new QTcpSocket(this);
sock->connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 1234);
connect(sock, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));
connect(sock, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), 
          this, SLOT(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
```

I will get the error() signal.

```
sock->close();
sock->deletelater();
```

I use a timer to try to connect, and it did call the error() to delete the sock.
But I found that the handles increase in the Task Manager. Does it have memory leak? but I have close the sock and use deletelater().
What's more, the socket object not run in the main thread.

If any one know the reason cause the handles increase, please tell me.
Thanks!

Comment: And if you don't connect (and don't even create the socket object), does the handle leak stop?

Comment: Yes, it will stop. And if I open the server let it connect success, it will stop too. Does close() function not close the handle?

Comment: And if you wait a couple of minutes (to let the socket leave the [`TIMEWAIT` or `CLOSE WAIT` states](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/Tcp_state_diagram_fixed.svg)), will the number of handles still increase?

Comment: Yes, I change the timer interval to 5 minutes, it still increase.